# Java Unicode characters to UTF

Tags: java, string, unicode, utf-8

In Java, how can I convert a string containing unicode characters escaped to utf 8, e.g. from Rüppell's_Vulture to R%c3%bcppell's_Vulture

Comment: %c3% is not UTF-8 but html-escape

Comment: @Uwe: `%c3` is not [HTML-escaping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references), but [URL-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Comment: user1774937: your question is very strange. You're clearly mixing some basic concepts. What exactly do you ultimately want to do with the escaped/encoded string? I.e. what exactly is the functional requirement for which you thought that this would possibly be the right solution? Only then, the right answer can be given.

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = URLDecoder.decode("R%c3%bcppell's_Vulture", "UTF-8");
String s = URLEncoder.encode("Rüppell's_Vulture", "UTF-8");
```

With % it is an URL encoding.

Comment: its doing the reverse, i.e. R%c3%bcppell to Rüppell

Answer (score 0):

Copy it to byte array with getBytes("UTF-8). Like this:

```
byte[] utf = String.getBytes("UTF-8")
```

Do not know the way of dealing with it just with Strings (I believe they have fixed encoding).